# Disable textfield on Touch UI cq dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, aem

I want to call a JS function on load of cq dialog to validate if a field already has something if so, disable it from the edition. I have tried with validation but it is called after the users interact with the field, I need a way to do it before when is being loaded. Is it possible?

```
<id
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
   fieldLabel="ID"
   validation="is_empty" // DO THIS WHEN IS LOADED
   name="./id"
   required="{Boolean}true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a way to achieve this using `cq.authoring.dialog` clientlib and `jQquery`

- Create a clientlib with categories as `cq.authoring.dialog`. Scripts in this clientlib are loaded only in the [author instance](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/developing-components.html#CreatingaClientLibraryforStyleandBehavior).
- Add a class to the text field using the `granite:class` attribute, this is to hook onto the textfield using script in the above clientlib

> ```
>           <id
>             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
>             sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
>             fieldLabel="ID"
>             granite:class="readonlySelector"
>             name="./id"
>             required="{Boolean}true"/>
> ```

- You will have to include the below namespace in `dialog.xml` to use`granite:class`.
  `xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0"`
- Notice the class name registered above in the DOM

[image]

- Use one of the OOTB granite event listeners like `foundation-contentloaded` to fire the script on initialization of the dialog. You could probably use a more narrower event, check out [granite documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation/vocabulary/index.html) for more events
- Use the [Coral UI Textfield documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Textfield.html) to find out supported attributes. `disabled` and `readonly` are supported. Place this code in the `cq.authoring.dialog` clientlib.

> ```
> $(document).on('foundation-contentloaded', function (e) {//event fires when dialog loads
>     var $textField = $('.readonlySelector');
>     if ($textField.val()) {//truthy check
>         $textField.prop('disabled', true);//Greys the field
>         $textField.prop('readonly', true);
>     }
> })
> ```

- Grayed and disabled

[image]